# Attaching a file with a worksheet to be emailed

Tags: vba, excel, email

Just to give you a bit of a background, I am an IT contractor. I was looking for an accountancy package that I could use to do my day to day accounting. After searching for nearly 2 weeks, I was not happy with anything out there. So I've decided to build my own on Excel. I have listed requirements to that end. One of my requirements for the package is to be able to attach files with my workbook so that I can then send them to my accountant. Attachments will be invoices, receipts, expenses etc. My question is, is there a way to attach files with workbook that I can then email with the workbook? I know I can attach files within a workbook but that uses local UNC path and that wont work when I email the workbook. I am not using outlook so that is not something I can tap into. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score -1):

Click where you want to embed a file and go to the `Insert` ribbon. Then choose `Object`, followed by `Create from file`, and browse to the file. This should 'attach' the file rather than just linking to it.

Comment: thanks fir the reply but I'm looking for a VBA option. I will try to do your suggestion via VBA